# Empty values on Ajax response using coffeescript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I've got ajax in the coffee script - which send values to back-end. In browser-panel I could see response with json inside, but on success - all variables is undifined. Could somebody help with it?

here is code of the ajax.

```
    $.post '/articles/' + id + '/comments',
  contentType: 'application/json'
  data: comment_params:
    commenter: commenter
    body: body
  success: (data, textStatus, jQxhr) ->
    console.log(textStatus)
    $('#comments').append JSON.stringify(data)
  dataType: 'json'
```

All variables `data, textStatus, jxQhr` are undifined. How could I get this values from those variables?

Comment: [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is called as `$.post(url, data, success, dataType)` **or** `$.post(settings_object)`, aren't you mixing these two calling conventions? Also, are you sure you need to manually call `JSON.stringify` rather than just handing an object to `data:`?

Comment: @muistooshort I removed JSON.stringify from form-data - but still empty values.

Comment: But you're still trying to mix the two different ways of calling `$.post`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the docs for what you're trying to do:

[$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

[$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

This is two ways to perform a post, but they have different method signatures.

Like is said in a comment, what you have here is a mix of the different syntaxes, which isn't valid for either.

For the most part, it looks like the `$.ajax` signature, so you can change it slightly like so (note I also fixed the indentation - try and get this right when you post code in a question, since it's significant for languages like coffeescript):

```
# Note i'm using string interpolation, not concatenation
$.ajax "/articles/#{id}/comments",
  # add this key-val to determine the request type
  method: "POST"
  contentType: 'application/json'
  data: comment_params:
    commenter: commenter
    body: body
  success: (data, textStatus, jQxhr) ->
    console.log(textStatus)
    $('#comments').append JSON.stringify(data)
  dataType: 'json'
```